# Car doesn't cold start on first go

Tags: bmw, cold-start

Model: BMW 330i E46 (6 Cyl)

Port Fuel Injection

New spark plugs, old coils

New fuel filter (and regulator)

Problem: On a cold start, the engine will crank, fire and turn over by itself for about 1 second, then the following will happen:

1. It will immediately die
2. The engine will stutter, RPMs drop to around 500, and the engine will "catch" itself and recover (within 2-3 seconds).

If the engine is started immediately after the first cold start, none of this happens and it cold starts like normal. If I blip the throttle immediately after starting, the RPM's increase (as expected). The fuel pump primes for a few seconds on ignition. No engine codes or lights come up (checked using a BMW diagnostics tool).

How should I start my diagnosis? It feels like a fuel issue, but how much fuel pressure do you need to start a car? At WOT, there's no issue and plenty of power.

Comment: You will need the same fuel pressure to start the car as it needs to run at full throttle.  The quantity of fuel will be different, but the pressure should be the same.

Comment: First thing I would do would be to find and test the engine coolant temperature sensors, then then air intake temperature sensors.

Comment: What do you mean test them? I have checked with the bmw diagnostic tools and the values they are reporting look correct (i.e. ambient temperature)

Comment: If the diagnostics indicate that they are OK, then they will be.  You didn't say that you have used a diagnostic tool.  Maybe you should add that to your question.  Did the diagnostics show anything?

Comment: @HandyHowie updated it. No codes or errors triggered.

Comment: @tgun926 What happens on a cold start if you turn the key half-way (so the dashboard lights come on and the fuel pump is primed etc), wait for 5 seconds, and only _then_ turn the key all the way to crank the engine? Does doing this make the problem less severe or even go away completely?

Comment: @marcelm I've tried waiting for the fuel pump to turn off after ignition and crank it while priming, but it makes no difference. I've tried priming it multiple times (ignition on then off then on) and then cranking it, but still no difference.